# :onclick and formtastic: Disabling commit button after first click prevents form from processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, onclick, formtastic

I am trying to make sure the users of my rails app can not submit my formtastic forms multiple times by double clicking.

See my code below.

Unfortunately, after adding the :onclick argument to the commit button, the form does not process anymore. The button name simple changes to a disabled button 'Processing...' (as expected during submission) but this state is permanent (no data validation and redirect as before).

I fail to see how to debug this - can anybody help?

```
= semantic_form_for @case, :html => {:class => "form-stacked"} do |f|  
    = f.inputs :name => "Case" do
    = f.input  :summary, :input_html => {:class => 'xxlarge main_case'}
= f.buttons do
  = f.commit_button "Create Case", :button_html => {:class => "btn primary", :onclick => "this.disabled=true; this.value='Processing...';"}
```

Answer (score 6):

just try:

```
submit_tag "Create Case", :disable_with => "Processing..."
```

this will work in rails 3 and above

Update:

with formtastic you need the following

```
<%= f.action :submit, :button_html => { :label => "create case", :class => "btn primary", :disable_with => 'Processing...' } %>
```

Comment: I tried this but I still manage to create several form submissions by double/triple clicking. How long does this disable the button?

Comment: Writing it like you did yields error: undefined method `action' for #<Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder:0x007fad95d9a7e8>

Comment: So like I said before I tried this:       = f.commit_button "Create Case", :button_html => {:class => "btn primary", :disable_with => 'Processing...'}      but this does not prevent double submitting...

Comment: do you have the 'jquery-rails'gem in your gem file? and included jquery and jquery_ujs in your application layout ?

Comment: No I don't but I do have jquery.js file that I call in my application layout.

Comment: try adding the gem, i have just tried and it dose nto work without it... it, i think it might be because you need jquyer-ujs as well so you could try installing that, but then that is what the gem is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using rails 3, you would actually want to do that on "onsubmit" on the form element, since pressing enter keys in text fields etc can trigger submit event.

Make sure you "return true" in your js code for the form to actually submit after you disable the button.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on onsubmit, although my form does not submit when the enker key is used in the text field. I do not understand what you say about the js code, I am not writing any here.

Comment: Okay of course the string inside the hash is javascript, my bad. I tried to add return true but does not work, here is the updated line: = f.commit_button "Create Case", :button_html => {:class => "btn primary", :onclick => "this.disabled=true; this.value='processing...'; return true;"} Tried with :onsubmit too.